# Transposing a pandas col into a row, using another col as an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to transpose a column within a dataframe so that it becomes a row, while using another row as the index. Specifically, I need all *ColB* values where *ColA == '1'* to become the values for *RowA*, and all the *ColB* where *ColA == '2'* to become the values for *RowB*.

i.e. I need to turn:

```
index    ColA    ColB
    0     1.0     1.1
    1     1.0    12.2
    2     1.0     4.5
    3     2.0     5.1
    4     2.0     7.7
    5     2.0     9.5
```

into ...

```
        ColB
           0       1      2
ColA
 1.0     1.1    12.2    4.5
 2.0     5.1     7.7    9.5
```

------ Update #1 --------

In reference to the answer provided by @Scott_Boston:

```
df.groupby('ColA').apply(lambda x: x.reset_index().ColB)
```

seems to give me:

```
ColA
 1.0    0     1.1
        1    12.2
        2     4.5
 2.0    0     5.1
        1     7.7
        2     9.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby('ColA').ColB.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).rename_axis('ColB',1)
Out[113]: 
ColB    0     1    2
ColA                
1.0   1.1  12.2  4.5
2.0   5.1   7.7  9.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `groupby`, `apply`, and `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby('ColA').apply(lambda x: x.reset_index().ColB)
```

Output:

```
ColB    0     1    2
ColA                
1.0   1.1  12.2  4.5
2.0   5.1   7.7  9.5
```

Comment: nice usage for apply ~ :)

Comment: Thanks for posting! Unfortunately this didn't seem to transpose the ColB column into a row - I'm not sure why. See the update on the OP for details.